# I was less able to login my Django app with facebook account with AttributeError

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-3.x, python-social-auth

Excuse me, but after I added following code to get email, I became unable to log in my app with facebook account.

settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id,name,email', 
}
```

And the error is here.

> AttributeError at /complete/facebook/ 'NoneType' object has no
>   attribute 'provider'

Debug-toobar

```
/home/hoge/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/social/actions.py in do_complete

    social_user.provider)

▼ Local vars
backend <social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2 object at 0x9f74fcr31r68>
redirect_name 'next'
args ()
login   <function _do_login at 0x9f74fcr31r68>
is_new False
partial None
social_user None
kwargs {}
is_authenticated False
```

What should I do for this?

Thank you.

python: 3.5.1, Django 1.9.2, python-social-auth: 0.2.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so sorry.
I could solve this by myself.

After I deleted my database, it worked.